# How to connect to a mlab mongodb database in go(lang)?

Tags: mongodb, go, driver

I have a mlab MongoDB database called storyfactory.
This database has a collection called test, which has a user called Standard with a Password.

I'm trying to connect to the database with this [Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver).
This is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func main() {
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://<Standard>:<Password>@ds127101.mlab.com:27101/storyfactory"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    collection := client.Database("storyfactory").Collection("test")
    ctx, _ = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    res, err := collection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.M{"name": "pi", "value": 3.14159})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res.InsertedID)
}
```

If I try to run this code, I get following output:

```
2019/03/12 18:09:04 auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
exit status 1
```

I'm 100% sure that the Password is correct.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you copy & paste the same credentials into `mongo -u -p` it works? "Authentication failed" is pretty hard to argue with as errors go.

Comment: Try reaching out to mLab's support team (support@mlab.com). They can help troubleshoot these types of issues.

Comment: Did you try to specify auth mechanis? Url like that `mongodb://<Standard>:<Password>@ds127101.mlab.com:27101/storyfactory?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1`. Also which version of mongo driver are you using?

Comment: I now deleted my mlab account and then signed up for a new one. It seems like they are redirecting all their users to mongo cloud now. However, I now use a slightly different URI, but it works! Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Glad you have it working now @Tobi696. For background information, mLab is now part of MongoDB. See https://blog.mlab.com/2018/10/mlab-is-becoming-a-part-of-mongodb-inc/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kind of late to the game, but the documentation has all the answers.

https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?tab=doc#example-Connect-SCRAM

Basically, you shouldn't pass your username and password into the connection URI but rather set them as options (see full example below)

```golang
// Configure a Client with SCRAM authentication (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-scram/).
// The default authentication database for SCRAM is "admin". This can be configured via the
// authSource query parameter in the URI or the AuthSource field in the options.Credential struct.
// SCRAM is the default auth mechanism so specifying a mechanism is not required.

// To configure auth via URI instead of a Credential, use
// "mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017".
credential := options.Credential{
    Username: "user",
    Password: "password",
}
clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017").SetAuth(credential)
client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOpts)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
_ = client
```

I've had so many "issues" with this driver, and they were all fixable after I decided to really look at the docs.

Happy hacking!

Comment: I tried same way . Its working fine in terminal. But in my code still getting same error which is mentioned above.